# How to set canvas translation to top left corner after rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm drawing a symbol with simple lines, but want the user to be able to specify the rotation (in 90degrees only).
Which also means that the dimensions of my canvas change.

No I calculate the dimensions, and set the canvas size. Then I set the center of the rotation to the center of my canvas (via `ctx.translate`) and rotate to the arbitrary degrees.

Now my problem is: How do I set the translation back to the upper left corner, so I can draw my symbol normally from that position? Do I really have to calculate the values with the rotation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  `translate` `rotate` and `scale` are all functions that operate upon the current matrix.  This gives you lots of options.  Probably the simplest thing is to do a save restore on the context matrix

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate ( to the center );
ctx.rotate ( do rotation );
//Draw rotated stuff
ctx.restore();
//Draw non-rotated stuff
```

Now after you call restore, the matrix reverts to how it was before the last save - In opengl, this is actually a stack, and you can push many contexts, but I'm not sure if webgl supports that.

This link may also be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas

Hope this helps.

Update:

Yes.  Okay, so you are misunderstanding something a little bit.  The translations and rotations are applied *before* the drawing.  This is because of a lot of complex math, and is really beyond the scope of this question.  So if you want to draw part of your canvas rotated one way, and the other part of it rotated a different way, you first `save`, then apply the transformations, do the first part of the drawing, then `restore` to get back to the pre-transformed state.  At which point, you can repeat.
So, for example, you can do this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate ( x_center, y_center );
ctx.rotate ( 90 );
//Draw your rotated stuff starting at the center
ctx.translate ( -x_center, -y_center );
//Draw your main frame stuff that is all rotated around the center
ctx.restore();
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate ( 90 );
//Draw your text which is rotated around the top-left corner
ctx.restore();
```

In this way, you have 1 drawing function, and you simply setup a context before you draw the different components.

Comment: Mh, but won't all the lines I'm going to draw be translated by the first `ctx.translate (to center)`. That's the thing I can't figure out.. I want the rotation to rotate around the center, but the rotated lines I draw afterwards to be from the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help idbentley, but won't this translate be rotated as well?

Comment: Sorry, I think that I misunderstood again.  So what you want is the text to write in the actual top-left corner, not the top-left corner before rotation.  In this case, I don't understand why you are rotating around the center?

Comment: This wasn't very clear.  If you want text in the top left which is rotated, you should rotate it from the top left, not from the center.  If you have other things that you want to rotate around the center, you should use the `save`, `restore` technique described above.

Comment: Ok... I'm sorry, I am apparently very bad in explaining this. If I rotate the context from the top left, then my drawing will not remain in the center of the canvas (since if I rotate 90deg clockwise, the whole canvas will have disappeared). That's why I have to rotate from the center. So I have **one** drawing function, that draws the same symbol, and the `ctx.rotate` function before makes sure it's rotated correctly. But the problem is, that my drawing function does not draw from the top left anymore, and thus, is not centered. Was that clear?

Comment: Thanks again for your help idbentley, but I don't misunderstand the concept of canvas transformations (at least I don't think I do). The problem I'm having, is: my drawing function works from the **top left corner** and _not_ from the **center** of the canvas. So: you're suggesting to `save`, `translate`, `rotate` and then draw the stuff I want rotated. But this is where I encounter my problem: This will not only be rotated, but also translated... so my drawing will be in the wrong place.

Comment: Update to the code above: This is because of how the context matrix multiplication works - you translate to the center so that the rotation which is applied to the matrix will be around the center, and then you translate back to the corner, so that your drawing occurs up there.  It takes some getting used to, but translate - rotate - translate is different from translate - translate - rotate!